# Python3 listing all files/directories on same level as certain folder name

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I have a path like this:

```
/my/path/to/important_folder
```

on the same level, I have other files and folders that I want to list when I reach the same level as `important_folder`.

My folder could be deeper, so I need to traverse through the folders until I reach `important_folder` keep searching. Once found, list all files/folders in that same level.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `os.walk`, you can do this:

```
import os
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('/my/path'):
    if path == 'important_folder':
        for name in dirs + files:
            print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

Or you can use `glob.iglob` with `recursive=True`:

```
import glob
for name in glob.iglob('/my/path/**/important_folder/*', recursive=True):
    print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!